# I want to retrieve server info which have only 20% of remaining space in D drive using powershell script

Tags: powershell

My Script :

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_logicalDisk -ComputerName server1, server2, server3, etc | 
  Select-Object pscomputername, deviceid, freespace, size | 
  Out-File c:\test.txt
```

the above script gives me all the drive space avaliabilty along with drive, total space in the server.

I want to display only the servers which have 20% of space availability in D drive of the total space avaliability.

Please help me to write the logic in powershell script.

and how do I show the report in a HTML page?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `where` clause to filter:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_logicalDisk -ComputerName server1, server2, server3, etc | 
Select-Object pscomputername, deviceid, freespace, size | 
? {$_.size -ne $null -and ($_.freespace / $_.size) -gt 0.2} |
Out-File c:\test.txt
```

This will return drives with more than 20% free.

Comment: @PraveenSaboji - you're welcome. Feel free to upvote the answer!